# Use Amazon S3 after AWSCognitoIdentityProvider Authentication

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

I want to upload images to Amazon S3 from Android Device, that is working fine by initializing Amazon S3 client with this code

```
s3Client = new AmazonS3Client( new BasicAWSCredentials( ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY ) );
```

What if I want to use this **s3Client** after i have authenticated the user with **AWSCognitoIdentityProvider**, how would I be able to restrict users from using **Amazon S3** in my app.

I am getting token and identity id from my own Backend Server using CognitoAPI, but how can I utilize this cognitoProvider to restrict Amazon S3 access.

If there is a way to do this using **Amazon Cognito** then please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permission is defined via the IAM roles which are passed into the Cognito credentials provider. To learn more about the provider, please refer to the [Amazon Cognito Identity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html) and a blog post [Using the Amazon Cognito Credentials Provider](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/cognito-auth.html).

Comment: "I am getting token and identity id from my own Backend Server using CognitoAPI" - Anyone can invoke the same API and get the token - how are you preventing that?